# Is there a counterexample? $\forall\ p \gt 3 \in \Bbb P, (number\ of\ Quadratic\ Residues\ mod\ kp)=p\ when\ k\in\{2,3\}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratic-residues

I have started to learn about the properties of the [quadratic residues modulo n (link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue) and reviewing the list of quadratic residues modulo $n$ $\in [1,n-1]$ I found the following possible property:

> (1) $\forall\ p \gt 3\in \Bbb P, \ (number\ of\ Quadratic\ Residues\ mod\ kp)=p\ when\ k\in\{2,3\}$

In other words: (a) if $n$ is $2p$ or $3p$, where $p$ is a prime number greater than $3$, then the total number of the quadratic residues modulo $n$  is exactly the prime number $p$. (b) And every prime number $p$ is the number of quadratic residues modulo $2p$ and $3p$.

> E.g.:
>
> $n=22$, the list of quadratic residues is $\{1,3,4,5,9,11,12,14,15,16,20\}$, the total number is $11 \in \Bbb P$ and $22=11*2$.
>
> $n=33$, the list of quadratic residues is $\{1,3,4,9,12,15,16,22,25,27,31\}$, the total number is $11 \in \Bbb P$ and $33=11*3$.

I did a quick Python test initially in the interval $[1,10^4]$, no counterexamples found. Here is the code:

```
def qrmn():
    from sympy import is_quad_residue
    from gmpy2 import is_prime

    def list_qrmn(n):
        lqrmn = []
        for i in range (1,n):
            if is_quad_residue(i,n):                    
                lqrmn.append(i)
        return lqrmn

    tested1 = 0
    tested2 = 0
    for n in range (4,10000,1):
        lqrmn = list_qrmn(n)
        # Test 1
        if is_prime(len(lqrmn)):
            if n==3*len(lqrmn) or n==2*len(lqrmn):
                print("SUCCESS1 " + str(n) + " len " + str(len(lqrmn)) + " div " + str(int(n/len(lqrmn))))
                tested1 = tested1 + 1

        # Test 2
        if n==3*len(lqrmn) or n==2*len(lqrmn):
            if is_prime(len(lqrmn)):
                print("SUCCESS2 " + str(n) + " len " + str(len(lqrmn)) + " div " + str(int(n/len(lqrmn))))
                tested2 = tested2 + 1
            else:
                print("ERROR2 " + str(n) + " len " + str(len(lqrmn)) + " div " + str(int(n/len(lqrmn))))

    if tested1 == tested2:
        print("\nTEST SUCCESS: iif condition is true")
    else:
        print("\nTEST ERROR: iif condition is not true: " + str(tested1) + " " + str(tested2))

qrmn()
```

I am sure this is due to a well known property of the quadratic residues modulo $n$, but my knowledge is very basic (self learner) and initially, reviewing online, I can not find a property of the quadratic residues to understand if that possible property is true or not.

Please I would like to share with you the following questions:

> 1. Is (1) a trivial property due to the definition of the quadratic residue modulo n?
> 2. Is there a counterexample?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "the length of the quadratic residues"? Do you just mean, the number of quadratic residues?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, the number of quadratic residues, I wanted to mean the lenght of the set of quadratic residues...

Comment: Then let me suggest you edit the quesiton so it says that.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you, done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, Let $N(n) = \{\textrm{the number of quadratic residues in Z/nZ}\}$.

Then for $n,m$ coprime, $N(nm) = N(n)N(m)$. This will follow from the chinese remainder theorem($Z/mnZ = Z/mZ\times Z/nZ$) and basic group theory. Try working through the details.

Example:  For $p$ prime: $N(p) = p+1/2, 0$ is a square. $N(2) = |\{0,1\}| = 2, N(3) = |\{0,1\}| = 2$ . I get $p+1$ since I am including $0$ and the op isn't.

Comment: But $N(p)=\frac{p-1}{2}$ if $p$ is an odd prime, which seems to contradict the statement...

Comment: @Asvin  thank you for taking time to answer, please  may I ask you for an specific example of n,m for this generalization? I get lost in your nice theoretical explanation. Probably with a very specific example I would see it clear.

Comment: @Nishant $N(p) = p+1/2, 0$ is a square. $N(2) = |\{0,1\}| = 2, N(3) = |\{0,1\}| = 2$ . I get $p+1$ since I am including $0$ and the op isn't.

Comment: @iadvd I have added an example. Try counting with p = 5, n = 10 if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

The Chinese Remainder theorem lets us conclude that counting squares mod $mn$ is the same as counting pairs of squares mod $m$ and mod $n$ separately...whenever $m,n$ are coprime.

Note that there are exactly two squares mod $2$ and same mod $3$.

It is also known that modulo an odd prime there are $\frac{p-1}{2} + 1$ squares (including $0 \bmod p$).

So putting this together, when counting squares mod $2p$ or $3p$ and $p>3$ (so is coprime to $2,3$) we should get exactly $2(\frac{p-1}{2}+1) = p+1$ squares.

You seem to be discounting $0 \bmod kp$ as a square, hence why you got exactly $p$ non-zero squares.

Comment: thank you, easy to follow answer for my level!!

Comment: I was reviewing your nice answer, may I ask you something very simple? About your phrase, "counting squares mod mn is the same as counting pairs of squares mod m and mod n separately... whenever m,n are coprime".  If I understood, then does that mean that "counting squares mod mn" is a multiplicative function? (like Totient function, Mobius, etc.) Thank you! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function

Comment: Yes, which is what was said in Asvin's answer. It is just a consequence of the CRT.

Comment: Have you tried the same for $4p$? It should still work since there are exactly two squares mod $4$. However the result will not work for $kp$ if $k>4$ since there are definitely more than $2$ squares mod $k$ ($0,1,4,...$).

Comment: yes, $4p$ is also working. When I did the test I did not know why the results were ok up to a certain value of $kp$. Another interesting point is that certain primes are able of "hitting" quadratic residue mod n lists of size a prime number over $4p$, for instance $p=11$ is able to "hit" primes up to $k=9$, $9*11=99$, so it is also interesting to know which one of them are able to hit primes up to for instance $p\cdot(p-1)$, if any. But that is another history. :)

Answer (score 1):

Say $N=2p$ then 
$$\#\{y:x^2\equiv y(\ {\rm{mod}} N)\}$$ is equal (from CRT) 
$\#\{y:x^2\equiv y(\ {\rm{mod}} p)\}\times 2-1=p$ (we subtract $-1$ since we add the solution $x=0$ twice. We have $\frac{p+1}{2}\times 2$ equations but two of them are the same.). 
More general if $N=p_1p_2\cdots p_k$ and $p_j$ are distinct odd primes then you get
$\frac{1}{2^n}\prod_{i=1}^n(p_i+1)-1.$